# Trouble deleting cookie in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I'm trying to implement a button that will delete a cookie when clicked. I set the cookie in PHP as follows: `setcookie('mycookie', $value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");`

In my JavaScript I have,

```
$('#mybtn').click(function() {
    document.cookie = "mycookie=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; domain=lab.school.edu; path='/';";
})
```

FireBug shows the following information: Name: mycookie, Domain: lab.school.edu, Path: /

All of this information matches up to the code snippet shown above so I have no idea why it's not working. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: from `path='/';` to `path=/;`

Comment: @Federico No success unfortunately

Comment: Check your syntax ( braces and parenthesis). That and the above comment by Federico should have it working.

Comment: did you have that page under `lab.school.edu` domain?

Comment: @Federico yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Too many parenthesis can stop the flow of the code. I would delete them in pairs, starting with your variable, until it starts working. The curly braces are needed.

Comment: Not sure where you mean. Looked over it a few times now and I can't see any mismatched parenthesis in the code snippet I provided.

Comment: In pure javascript you would not need a wrapper around the variable #mybtn. It would just be: mybtn.click(function() { code })/:}) unless the id of the button is #mybtn, then that is what you would use. It is a literal.